# Changing content storage path for Azure pack websites

Tags: windows, storage, azure, network-attached-storage

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the content storage location within Windows Azure pack websites.

I want to change my existing cloud's storage from a standalone Windows file server to a Linux NAS.

It seems the only way to do so would be to uninstall the hosting framework and reinstall.

There's a couple of configuration values in the hosting database which relate to this:
ContentShare
ContentShareLocalPath
FileServerProductIds
FileServerType

Technet seems to be lacking in any useful information relating to Azure pack websites.

Any help would be appreciated.